# Разница между файлами в компоненте catalog.section

Tags: php, веб-программирование, битрикс, компоненты

В чем разница между файлами section.php и sections.php и section_vertical.php и section_horisontal.php (в смысле их **назначения** и **структуры**) в компоненте битрикса catalog.section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, имеется в виду комплексный компонент bitrix:catalog, а не простой компонент bitrix:catalog.section.

Указанные файлы предназначены для поддержки ЧПУ https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=34&LESSON_ID=10233

Соответственно, когда комплексный компонент понимает, что именно он должен показывать, он выбирает соответствующий файл: sections.php для показа списка подразделов, section.php для показа содержимого подраздела и element.php для показа элемента инфоблока.

В шаблоне .default имеются дополнительные настройки. В частности, можно выбрать, показывать фильтр вертикально или горизонтально. Для этого и используются файлы section_vertical.php и section_horisontal.php.

Что касается структуры, то в этих файлах просто подключаются соответствующие простые компоненты.